# 'IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing this code but I have a problem in the line 40, with a Index Error. I don't know if there is a problem with the `nr-1`, inside the `for`.

The code:

```
import numpy


Z = 1
R = 1
nr = 5
nz = 4
kn = 1
ks = 1
ke = 1
kw = 1

T = numpy.zeros((nr, nz), dtype=float)

vetorq = 1




for a in range(1, 100, 1):
    for i in range(0, nz, 1):
        for j in range(0, nr, 1):



            an = (i + (1 / 2)) * (R ** 2)*nz*kn/ ((nr**2)* Z)
            ae = (i + 2) * Z*ke / nz
            aw = ((i+1)*kw * Z) / nz
            asul = (i + (1 / 2)) * (R ** 2)*nz*ks / (Z * (nr**2))
            ap = an + ae + aw + asul
            aef = 0



            if (i == 0 and j == 0):
                T[i, j] = ae * ((T[i, j + 1]) / ap) + asul * (
                            (T[i + 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap


            elif(i == 0 and j != 0 and j != nr - 1):
                T[i, j] = ae * ((T[i, j + 1]) / ap) + aw * ((T[i, j - 1]) / ap) + asul * (
                                (T[i + 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap


            elif(i == 0 and j == nr - 1):
                aef = (i + 2) * R * Z * vetorq / (nr * nz)
                T[i, j] = aw * ((T[i, j - 1]) / ap) + asul * (
                                (T[i + 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap

            elif(i != 0 and i != nz - 1 and j == nr - 1):
                aef = (i + 2) * R * Z * vetorq / (nr * nz)
                T[i, j] = aw * ((T[i, j - 1]) / ap) + an * ((T[i - 1, j]) / ap) + asul * (
                                (T[i + 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap

            elif(i == nz - 1 and j == nr - 1):
                aef = (i + 2) * R * Z * vetorq / (nr * nz)
                T[i, j] = aw * ((T[i, j - 1]) / ap) + an * ((T[i - 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) /((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap


            elif(i == nz - 1 and j != 0 and j != nr - 1):
                T[i, j] = ae * ((T[i, j + 1]) / ap) + aw * ((T[i, j - 1]) / ap) + an * ((T[i - 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap

            elif(i == nz - 1 and j == 0):
                T[i, j] = ae * ((T[i, j + 1]) / ap) + an * ((T[i - 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap

            elif(i != 0 and i != nz - 1 and j == 0):
                T[i, j] = ae * ((T[i, j + 1]) / ap) + an * ((T[i - 1, j]) / ap) + asul * (
                                (T[i + 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i + 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap

            elif(i != 0 and i != nz - 1 and j != 0 and j!= nr - 1):
                T[i, j] = ae * ((T[i, j + 1]) / ap) + aw * ((T[i, j - 1]) / ap) + an * ((T[i - 1, j]) / ap) + asul * (
                            (T[i + 1, j]) / ap) + 1846.35 * Z * (R ** 2) * (i - 1/2) / ((nr ** 2) * nz * ap) + aef / ap



print(T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you have interchanged nr(rows) and nz(columns) with the iterators i and j; Your two loops must be as shown below and change all if, elif conditions on i with (nr-1) and on j with (nz-1). It works fine.

```
for i in range(0, nr, 1):
    for j in range(0, nz, 1):
```